# C# Tweetinvi Library - how to stop stream

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

Attempting to get a filtered stream using the Tweetinvi library via c#.

I am trying to do something similar to the search, which I have been able to successfully receive tweets:

```
public List<ITweet> SearchTweets(string query)
{
    List<ITweet> tweets = new List<ITweet>();

    TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(Credentials, () =>
    {
        var searchParam = Search.GenerateSearchTweetParameter(query);
        searchParam.Lang = Language.English;
        searchParam.MaximumNumberOfResults = 100;
        tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParam);
    });

    return tweets;
}
```

but the limitation here is that I can only get a max 100 tweets. I want to leverage the stream in a similar way and get a stream of tweets matching the `tracks` that I pass. I have tried this:

```
public void FilterStream(string query)
{
    IFilteredStream tweets;

    TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(Credentials, () =>
    {
        var filteredStream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
        filteredStream.AddTrack(query);
        filteredStream.AddTrack("#" + query);
        filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => { Debug.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text); };
        filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
    });
}
```

but problem is it seems to run in an infinite loop and i'm unsure where to stop or limit the number of tweets I received from the stream to make it stop. The library's [documentation](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/documentation) is quite unclear and I have been unable to achieve the behavior I am seeking. I'm sure I am on the right route, just unsure how to stop the stream and store all the tweets I've received in a `List<ITweet>` construct.

Comment: Have you been able to fix your issue?

Comment: Please note the latest documentation can be found at : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Streams

Answer (score 1):

To stop the stream use:

```
filteredStream.StopStream();
```

You can keep a count of the tweets globally then stop when the number of tweets you need is received.

Comment: The execution of the program "hangs" after the `filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();` is executed. If I add a line with `filteredStream.StopStream();` the program never gets to executing it.

Comment: As mentioned in the example below you can use the Async version of the method or use a Thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up doing this:

```
var task = filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditionsAsync();

while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (ShouldStop)
    {
         filteredStream.StopStream();
         break;
    }
}

task.Wait();
```

`StartStreamMatchingAllConditionsAsync()` will start the task and return immediately, then the endless `while` loop will check for a condition to stop the stream and break the loop.

`ShouldStop` is a static boolean variable that is flipped to `True` when the code should stop streaming from twitter.

Then we `Wait()` for the stream task to finish.

That code *smells* but it seems to work! I'd be curious to see if someone comes up with a better implementation...

Comment: Well instead of having a global variable and a loop. Just store the stream object in the class that currently sets the global variable and call `stream.StopStream()` from there.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this answer but I can't make it work. 
The task is still never ending. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

- You should try to put a condition inside the MatchingTweetReceived method like this :

  ```
  public void FilterStream(string query)
  ```

  {
      IFilteredStream tweets;

  ```
  TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(Credentials, () =>
  {
      var filteredStream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
      filteredStream.AddTrack(query);
      filteredStream.AddTrack("#" + query);
      filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => { 

            Debug.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text); 
            if (condition)
              stream.StopStream();
  ```

  };
          filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
      });
  }

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I've just done this:

```
    public void Start()
    {
        _stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream(_creds);

        // Do whatever stream setup you want to do

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread started");
            _stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread stopped");
            });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stream.StopStream();
    }
```